# rand() function not working as expected (nested within foreach())?

Tags: php, loops, random

The idea is that a max and a minimum value are posted, and then a random number between the two is generated.

For example, `$mins = array(30,40,50,60)` and `$maxs = array(40,50,60,70)`, and then my code:

```
foreach($mins as $minkey => $maxval) {
    foreach($maxs as $maxkey => $maxval) {
            $hits[$maxkey] = rand($minval,$maxval);
    }
}
```

If I then `var_dump($mins)`, `var_dump($maxs)` and `var_dump($hits)`, I get:

```
array(4) { [1]=> string(2) "30" [2]=> string(2) "40" [3]=> string(2) "50" [4]=> string(2) "60" } array(4) { [1]=> string(2) "40" [2]=> string(2) "50" [3]=> string(2) "60" [4]=> string(2) "70" } array(4) { [1]=> int(27) [2]=> int(36) [3]=> int(19) [4]=> int(41) }
```

I thought the fact that `$maxs` and `$mins` contained string values, while `$hits` containing integers (i.e. `rand()` requires integer inputs ?) might be the issue so I updated my loop to become:

```
foreach($mins as $minkey => $minval) {
    foreach($maxs as $maxkey => $maxval) {
        $minval = (int)$minval;
        $maxval = (int)$maxval;
            $hits[$maxkey] = rand($minval,$maxval);
    }
}
```

But on `var_dump($mins)`, `var_dump($maxs)` and `var_dump($hits)`, this was dumped:

```
array(4) { [1]=> string(2) "30" [2]=> string(2) "40" [3]=> string(2) "50" [4]=> string(2) "60" } array(4) { [1]=> string(2) "40" [2]=> string(2) "50" [3]=> string(2) "60" [4]=> string(2) "70" } array(4) { [1]=> int(0) [2]=> int(47) [3]=> int(0) [4]=> int(55) }
```

Does anyone have any idea why this isn't working as expected?

Any thoughts/answers/comments would be very much appreciated :)!

Comment: This code runs fine (see http://ideone.com/0xD5l).  There must be a bug elsewhere.

Comment: Oli, 20 and 13 aren't between 30-40 and 40-50?

Comment: Ah, I see you've just edited your question.  So let me rephrase; this code runs exactly as I would expect.

Comment: Are you trying to generate 4 random numbers or 16?

Comment: 4, in between different ranges (30-40),(40-50, etc, one per key. I've changed it now to using a `for()` loop as my keys are numeric, and it works fine, but I'm still not sure as to why it wasn't working using `foreach()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to do that?
if yes, you can't have one loop in another...

```
for($i = 1; $i <= sizeof($mins); $i++) {
  $hits[$i] = rand($mins[$i], $maxs[$i]);
}
```

Comment: Edited, but thanks for the basis. I really don't know why I wasn't using a `for()` loop in the first place, my keys are numeric and matching, so I should use it by default.

Comment: yes, I forgot the =1 to initialize... (I have accepted the edit ;o))

Answer (score 1):

For one you're overwriting your variables:

```
foreach($mins as $minkey => $maxval) {
    foreach($maxs as $maxkey => $maxval) {
            $hits[$maxkey] = rand($minval,$maxval);
    }
}
```

I'm assuming is supposed to be:

```
foreach($mins as $minkey => $minval) {
    foreach($maxs as $maxkey => $maxval) {
            $hits[$maxkey] = rand($minval,$maxval);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's probably the issue! Stupid me, I'll post back in a minute :).

Comment: Still dumps: `array(4) { [1]=> int(49) [2]=> int(53) [3]=> int(60) [4]=> int(63) }`. The last two value values fit within their right ranges (50 - 60), (60 - 70) but not the first two.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what the expected result is but try this :

```
for ($i=0, $len = count($mins); $i < $len; $i++) {
    $hits[$i] = rand($mins[$i], $maxs[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got a typo with your first foreach loop, it should be

```
foreach($mins as $minkey => $minval)
```

This is causing an E_NOTICE error to be thrown and also prevents rand from working since minval doesn't exist. It's always a good idea to have error_reporting set to show notices in development which you can easily do via adding this at the start of your code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

See [php error reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) for more information

Comment: Thanks for the idea, the issue was more than just that, but I'll definitely use error reporting from now on!